# mysql UPDATE not updating the mysql table row

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first time with UPDATE (mysql) this code isn't send the updates to my mysql database/table/row. I spent hours on php.net , but from what I can see at my current level or php knowledge its right and since I'm wrong, them I' dumb =}.
I turned loggin on mysql - nothing useful

This is from ZEND server: So it appears to be passing, but it is not updating in the mysql database.
Function Name: mysql_query
Function Arguments:
'UPDATE ads SET adcode = \'7000sbjhbjhbhjb\' WHERE ads_ID = 8'

any pointers/help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

// Report all Errors
//error_reporting(-1);
//ini_set('display_errors','On');

//connect to DB
mysql_connect("$host", "$db_user", "$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name"); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ads";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);

echo "<h1><center>AD's Currently Available</center></h1><br /><br />";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $ID = mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
    $adname = mysql_result($result,$i,"adname");
    $currentadcode = mysql_result($result,$i,"adcode");

// Delete AD item by ID number  
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action']));
if ($_GET['action'] == "deletead") {  // remove AD
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM ads where ID = '$_GET[IDnum]'");
    $i=$i++;
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

$letknown = "<b>AD removed</b><br />";

**// Edit AD code
if (isset($_POST['editad' . $ID])) {
    $newadcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode' . $ID]);
    $doedit = "UPDATE ads SET adcode = '" . $newadcode . "' WHERE ads_ID = " . $ID;
    $updatead = mysql_query($doedit);
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);**

}
$letknown = "<b>Ad Edited</b><br />";

    echo "<b>$ID : $adname</b><br /><a href=\"?action=deletead&IDnum=$ID\">Delete Ad</a><br /><br />\n";
    echo "Preview :<br /><div class=\"adcode\">$currentadcode</div><br /> \n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<form action=\"displayads.php\" name=\"addAD$ID\" method=\"post\">\n";
    echo "AD code (can be any type of script) text link, javascript or banner :<br />\n";
    echo "Code :<br /><textarea name=\"adcode$ID\" wrap=\"physical\" cols=\"60\" rows=\"5\" onKeyDown=\"textCounter(document.addAD$ID.adcode$ID,document.addAD$ID.remLen$ID,5000)\" onKeyUp=\"textCounter(document.addAD$ID.adcode$ID,document.addAD$ID.remLen$ID,5000)\">$currentadcode</textarea>";
    echo "<br /><input readonly type=\"text\" name=\"remLen$ID\" size=\"3\" maxlength=\"3\" value=\"5000\">Characters Left \n";
    echo "**<input type=\"submit\" name=\"editad$ID\" value=\"Edit AD Code\">**</form>\n";
    echo "<br /><hr />";

$i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't know PHP so I may be off on this, but it looks like you're deleting the very tuple from the database before you try to update it. As the tuple to be updated doesn't exist, you can't update it. What happens if you remove the deletion code?

Comment: @No'amNewman that code only executes when the delete action is triggered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing closing double quotes :

```
$doedit = "UPDATE ads SET adcode = '" . $newadcode . "' WHERE ads_ID = '". $ID."'";
```

Or simply write your query like this :

```
$doedit = "UPDATE ads SET adcode = '$newadcode' WHERE ads_ID = '$ID'";
```

**Use LIMIT 1 if you want to update only a single row**

Comment: zend reports:
Function Name: mysql_query
Function Arguments:
'UPDATE ads SET adcode = \'7000hghgvgh\\r\\nhbhbh\\r\\ndfdffg\\r\\ndggg\\r\\n\' WHERE ads_ID = \'8\' LIMIT 1'

Comment: that was the data i used. but it makes no sense why its not putting it in there, the database from zend is right

Comment: varchar(500) it works with the INSERT, but not with UPDATE if the datatype is wrong

Comment: `code`$doedit = "UPDATE ads SET adcode = '$newadcode' WHERE ads_ID = '$ID' LIMIT 1";`code`

Comment: weird indeed. i cant figure it out.
Function Name: mysql_query
Function Arguments:
'UPDATE ads SET adcode = \'7000sexhbhgbjhbjhbhj\' WHERE ads_ID = \'8\' LIMIT 1'
its passing it per zend server

Comment: I don't have any idea about zend, just helped you with the query, I don't know why that's escaping quotes around your id?

Comment: AHH i bet that is it
$newadcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode' . $ID]);

my code passes name=\"adcode$ID\" from the textareas on the page.
so it has to have dynamic adcode(some number)

Comment: ya there's something wrong, actually why you are concatenating it in post? concatenate it later

Comment: i did it like that because of 

`code`<input type=\"submit\" name=\"editad$ID\" value=\"Edit AD Code\">`code`

each button has a specific name with unique $ID

Comment: I found many issues in my crap code ={ After I was able to get the errors comming, I fixed all the issues and changed my query to this
 $doedit = "UPDATE `adgate`.`ads` SET `ads`.`adcode` = '$newadcode' WHERE `ads`.`ID` = '$ID' LIMIT 1" or die(mysql_error());
it now works thanks!!